# Render state with React, ES6 in my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and I've chosen to create a sample resume app using ES6.

Here is a sample of my code in `App.js`

```
class ContentBlock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { heading: '', body: '' };
    }
    setText() {
      this.setState({ heading: "I'm Daniel", body: "I am about to be twenty seven years old" });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      {this.setText.bind(this)}
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <Media>
          <Media.Left>
            <Image src={this.props.src}/>
          </Media.Left >
          <Media.Heading>{this.state.heading}</Media.Heading>
          <Media.Body>
            <p>{this.state.body}</p>
          </Media.Body>
        </Media>
      );
    }
  }
```

I'm using a combination of these three tutorials.

[Official React ES6 tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)

[BabelJs tutorial for React ES6](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus)

[Kirupa Tutorial on React](https://www.kirupa.com/react/dealing_with_state.htm)

Aside from a warning on my ESLint, I'm experiencing no errors but the text is not rendering.

#####Update

The `this.props.src` comes from a component that uses `ContentBlock` as sub component

```
class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ContentBlock src={danrubio} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I specify the image and pass it onto the `About` component which `ContentBlock` will inherit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this statement: `this.setText.bind(this)` does, is just binds `setText` function to the context, but doesn't invokes it. Even more, you are binding it to the same context that it already has. No need in binding here.

Just change this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  {this.setText.bind(this)}
}
```

To:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setText()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lazarev, this did the trick. As a quick follow up, on the React official tutorial there is an example provided for Es6 classes that has this line for the `Counter` class `<div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>`. As per your answer wouldn't this not invoke the `tick` function as well?

Comment: In this example, you dont want to invoke it when it rendrers, only when the div is clicked. So u are right, it wont invoke it untill its clicked

Comment: Glad to help you, Dan! No, these are different cases. When adding event handlers, you don't need the function to be applied right? You just describe what has to be done when click event is handled. So actually, you just pass the reference to the function. But in your case, you do need the function to be called in order to change component state.